# create an entry in local OData service

Tags: odata, postman

I am trying to create en entry in my local `OData` service like in [this example](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#create)

Using `Postman` I am making a `POST` request on `https://localhost:8090/odata/titles` with this `JSON` body

```
{
  "@odata.type":"SAPSybaseOData.titles",
  "title_id":"ZZ1234",
  "title":"new book",
  "type":"business",
  "pub_id":"1390",
  "price":1,
  "advance":1,
  "total_sales":1,
  "notes":"note",
  "pubdate":"/Date(581817600000)/",
  "contract":true
}
```

the `OData` service response status code is `400 - Bad request` with this `XML` body

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
   <code>30068</code>
   <message xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred while parsing the request body.</message>
</error>
```

my `OData` service `metadata` is

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
   <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="1.0">
      <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" Namespace="SAPSybaseOData">
         <EntityType Name="titles">
            <Key>
               <PropertyRef Name="title_id" />
            </Key>
            <Property Name="title_id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="6" Unicode="false" Collation="cp850" />
            <Property Name="title" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="80" Unicode="false" Collation="cp850" />
            <Property Name="type" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="12" Unicode="false" Collation="cp850" FixedLength="true" />
            <Property Name="pub_id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="4" Unicode="false" Collation="cp850" />
            <Property Name="price" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="true" Precision="14" Scale="4" />
            <Property Name="advance" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="true" Precision="14" Scale="4" />
            <Property Name="total_sales" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="notes" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="200" Unicode="false" Collation="cp850" />
            <Property Name="pubdate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" Precision="3" />
            <Property Name="contract" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
         </EntityType>
         <EntityContainer Name="SAPSybaseOData_Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
            <EntitySet Name="titles" EntityType="SAPSybaseOData.titles" />
         </EntityContainer>
      </Schema>
   </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

How can I create a new entry like in [this example](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#create)  ?
Am I missing something ? How come the example is working fine and I get a parsing error ?

Comment: What is the version of the OData service? OData V4 or OData V3 ? The example you pasted is OData V4 and OData V4 is not compatible with OData V3.

Comment: According to the metadata it is **version 1.0** : `DataServiceVersion="1.0"`

Comment: Even following the [version 2 create example](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/operations) witch appears to be backward compatible to version 1, using a `XML` body request I still get the same parsing error. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Lonut, the example you mentioned in the second line from bottom is about OData V4. And the server you are building is OData V1. V4 doesn't backward compatible to V1. You can get information about json verbose format of V1 from [odata-version-2-0](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/).
However, if you are implementing the service by yourself, I recommend you to try WebApi OData instead of this old library. About WebApi OData, you can refer [WebApi OData](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/)